# Update all the posts at once nothing want to add or delete only update so that post slug get automatically generated..

Tags: wordpress, post, updates

I have changed the default permalink of my website to Custom permalink (/%post-name%)
Now all posts require slug values .
which is not present currently.A slug is automatically added   when a post is published or updated if slug screen option is unable ,but in my case now i have unable the slug option for all post earlier this was disabled  and Now I  want to update each post nothing want to add or delete just want to update all posts .
Currently number of posts in database is 200000, 
Please suggest any efficient query or any method so that my task can be accomplished.

Thanks,
Monika

Answer (score 3):

Try this plugin, it should do the job:

http://www.jerrytravis.com/598/wordpress-plugin-to-generate-post-slugs

Also this chunk of code can do the job, but you have to add some limits to avoid the script to crash due to the max limit of execution:

```
// get all posts
$posts = get_posts( array (  'numberposts' => -1 ) );

    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {
        // check the slug and run an update if necessary 
        $new_slug = sanitize_title( $post->post_title );
        wp_update_post(
            array (
                'ID'        => $post->ID,
                'post_name' => $new_slug
            )
        );
    }
```

Credit for the code:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46086/regenerate-slugs-from-title-of-posts

Comment: Thanks @alesub The plugin is doing nothing no slugs are generated .and i have used above code in page.php so that when a page is loaded all post get there slugs but nothing is done...:(

Comment: oh sorry, I just realized: remove that if condition, right now it will never be true. After you remove it and run it one more time, it should work :)

Comment: I don't know how to mark your answer as solution...if you can then tell me plzz

Comment: Oh, if you take a look at the left of my comment, you'll see a 0 and two arrows, below there's a "check" icon, clicking on it will mark the comment as the solution :) thanks!